# Firebase Exponential Backoff with Unsent Subscriptors

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

recently i survey for push service.

The FCM document states that there is no limit to the number of support subscriptions for iOS & Android subject messaging.

And the frequency of subscriptions is limited by project, so if you send lots of subscription requests in a short period of time, the FCM server returns a 429 response code.

The question is

The FCM sends a subscription request for a specific topic.
After this, if you send lots of subscription requests in a short period of time, it will return a 429 response code.
As a result, the app server must handle [exponential backoffs.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff)
If so, when doing the exponential backoff method,

1. Is FCM aware of the number of unsubscribed subscriptions(=failed devices)?
2. When the FCM makes a request again, does it send the message only for the number of unsubscribed subscriptions(=failed devices)?

I wonder.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by an "unsubscribed subscription", nor by "unsent subscriptions". Can you describe these questions in different words?

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen. I'm sorry to have to ask you with confused words.  "unsubscribed subscription",  "unsent subscriptions". i mean these word for failed tokens.

Comment: sorry. replace failed tokens with failed devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is FCM aware of the number of unsubscribed subscriptions(=failed devices)?

If you send too many topic subscription request in short succession, you will get a 429 response code. That is all the API guarantees.

> When the FCM makes a request again, does it send the message only for the number of unsubscribed subscriptions(=failed devices)?

If you mean whether FCM can be told to send catchup messages to devices that previously were unable to subscribe, then the answer is "no".

Comment: Perhaps FCM has changed or perhaps I misunderstand the documentation (haven't implemented yet), but [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) seems to suggest that catchup messages can be delivered for up to 28 days (specified by publisher).

Comment: Messages that have been queued for delivery may indeed be kept. OP was asking specifically about **topic subscriptions** where this doesn't apply, as translation from topic to the device IDs (so-called fan-out) happens shortly after you all the API, so any subscriptions that happen after that fan-out won't get the messaeg.